# Lowering notebook resolution saves battery? Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, battery, battery-life

I've an HD Spectre 360 notebook and it comes with QHD resolution touchscreen display. If I set it to full-hd (1080p) resolution would that save battery? or because it's not in the native resolution it could consume even more? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will make a significant difference. It will affect it, I think to save energy, because the graphics card won't be working as hard. But it will only be minutes at most.

To make the biggest difference turn the brightness down to a still readable level but as low as you can. Even then you probably will not get more than 10 minutes --- depending on what the computer is doing. The screen being on is among the biggest drain of energy for computers.

Comment: Ok, but I don't need the qhd resolution. And I believe since there are so many less dots to render, the graphics power necessity would be much lower, and based on that, the power consumption?